# Can i install distribution build to my iphone?How can i test Distribution build?

Tags: ios4, distribution

I want to test my final distribution build before submitting on apple store.please any body have idea then share with me.

Answer (score 0):

IMO for testing your distributable, you'd have to build it using the ad-hoc profile, on a registered device. Once you are satisfied, you can go ahead and build it for the app store again.